Oracle SQL query using regexp_substr to get string between 2 strings
I am trying to retrieve data from a blob using regexp_substr.
Here is how the blob looks like
"select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from t1 where xyx;"

Required output is
t1
Instead of where in the blob, it could be fetch ,order by or group by.
I am trying with
REGEXP_SUBSTR(query_blob,'FROM\s(.*?)\s(WHERE|FETCH|ORDER|GROUP)',1,1,'i',1)
but this gives me output as
xyz), d from t1
Could any one please help me to get the table name between from and (where or fetch or group by or order by).

If you look closely, you'll see that the from keyword also appears inside the call to the upper() function.  Regex isn't very suitable here, because you have nested content.  In general, you would need to use a SQL parser.

Yes  , it has nested from

@Littlefoot No need to delete provided you give a caveat.

Assuming a simple Oracle SQL query (i.e. without nested/correlated sub-queries) then you can use the regular expression ([a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*|"[^"]+") to only match the characters in an unquoted or quoted identifier (if you are using other languages that use different quoted identifiers, such as square brackets or backticks, then you can also add those) based on the Database Object Naming rules:


Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

Nonquoted identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.
Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).



And follow it with your check for additional filter/aggregation clauses (there could also be an alias [which in other non-Oracle SQL dialects could be preceded by the AS keyword] and/or a HAVING clause with no GROUP BY clause or no filters).
Like this:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         query_blob,
         'FROM\s+([a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*|"[^"]+")'            -- FROM clause
         || '(\s+([a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*|"[^"]+"))?'          -- FROM Alias
         || '\s*(\s(WHERE|FETCH|ORDER|GROUP|HAVING)|$)', -- Filter/Aggregation Clauses
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS frm
FROM   table_name;

Which, for your sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (query_blob) AS
SELECT 'select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from t1 where xyx;' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



FRM




t1



fiddle

If you want to make the expression even more complicated then:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         query_blob,
         'FROM\s+'                                       -- FROM clause
         || '('
         ||   '([a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*|"[^"]+")'              -- Identifier
         ||   '(\(\s*'                                   -- Start Function call
         ||   '('                                        -- Start optional group
         ||   '[a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*'                        -- Unquoted identifier
         ||   '|"[^"]+"'                                 -- Or quoted identifier
         ||   '|''([^'']|'''')*'''                       -- Or string literal
         ||   ')?\s*'                                    -- End optional group
         ||   '('                                        -- Start zero-or-more group
         ||   ',\s*[a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*'                    -- Unquoted identifier
         ||   '|,\s*"[^"]+"'                             -- Or quoted identifier
         ||   '|,\s*''([^'']|'''')*'''                   -- Or string literal
         ||   ')*'                                       -- End zero-or-more group
         ||   '\s*\))?'                                  -- End Function call
         || ')'
         || '(\s+([a-z][a-z0-9_$#]*|"[^"]+"))?'          -- FROM Alias
         || '\s*(\s(WHERE|FETCH|ORDER|GROUP|HAVING)|$)', -- Filter/Aggregation Clauses
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS frm
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (query_blob) AS
SELECT 'select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from t1 where xyx;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from abc(''xyz'') where xyx;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from abc(def) where xyx;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from abc( def, ''ghi'', jkl ) where xyx;' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



FRM




t1


abc('xyz')


abc(def)


abc( def, 'ghi', jkl )



Or, if you want a simple expression that may be a 90% solution:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         query_blob,
         'FROM\s+'                                       -- FROM clause
         || '(\S+)'                                      -- Identifier
         || '(\s+(\S+))?'                                -- FROM Alias
         || '\s*(\s(WHERE|FETCH|ORDER|GROUP|HAVING)|$)', -- Filter/Aggregation Clauses
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS frm
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the same sample data, matches the first 3 rows but not the final one (as there are spaces inside the brackets of the function call).
fiddle

Could you please explain the regular expression part.

@SnehaS [a-z] is an alphabetic character, which matches the first character of an unquoted identifier, [a-z0-9_$#]* matches zero-or-more of the following characters in an unquoted identifier (see the documentation quoted in the answer) which, when put together, matches an unquoted identifier and "[^"]+" matches a quoted identifier. The rest is explained in the answer. What else did you need explaining?

why are we using the || in the regular expression part? Also if my from clause is like  from abc('xyx')  will I get abc('xyx') as the output?

@SnehaS abc('xyz') is not a valid Oracle identifier. If you have a function abc that generates a table-collection expression then abc('xyz') would be valid but once you start getting into that detail then you have not got a "simple" Oracle SQL statement and start getting to the point where you need to write a proper parser or else define the rules of what is an acceptable value to match in the FROM clause (which your question does not describe) and then you can work out whether the regular expression syntax is capable of handling those rules.

|| allows you to split the regular expression up into different parts and helps to logically organise the code with the inline comments.

@M10 Thank you for the solution and explanation.
I seem have to scenarios where abc('xyx') is valid and needs to be retrieved.

Since you are looking for text between last occurrences of predefined words if you want to do it without using regexp here is an option using just standard text functions:
WITH     -- cte acting as your sample table data
  texts (ID, TEXT) AS
    ( Select 1, '"select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from t1 where xyx;"'      From Dual Union All
      Select 2, '"select a,b,d,e from t22 fetch last one;"' From Dual Union All
      Select 3, '"select a,upper(c from xyz fetch 1 or 2 from tbl), d from t333 order by a;"'     From Dual Union All
      Select 4, '"select a,b ,upper(c from xyz group by c), d from t4t5t6 group by x,y;"'   From Dual 
    ), 

... you could create a cte to define border words combinations
--  cte defining border words - notice space character after word 1 and before word 2
  words (WORD_1, WORD_2) AS
    ( Select 'FROM ', ' WHERE'      From Dual Union All
      Select 'FROM ', ' FETCH'      From Dual Union All
      Select 'FROM ', ' ORDER BY'   From Dual Union All
      Select 'FROM ', ' GROUP BY'      From Dual 
    ), 

... another cte to get last positions of border words within the text
--  cte geting last position of words
  last_occurrences AS 
    ( Select     t.ID, w.WORD_1, w.WORD_2, 
                 Length(t.TEXT) - InStr(Upper(REVERSE(t.TEXT)), REVERSE(w.WORD_1)) + 1 "P1",
                 InStr(Upper(t.TEXT), w.WORD_2, Length(t.TEXT) - InStr(Upper(REVERSE(t.TEXT)), REVERSE(w.WORD_1)) + 1, 1)  "P2"
      From       texts t
      Inner Join words w ON( InStr(Upper(t.TEXT), w.WORD_1) > 0 And 
                             InStr(Upper(t.TEXT), w.WORD_1) > 0 
                           )
     Where     InStr(Upper(t.TEXT), w.WORD_2, Length(t.TEXT) - InStr(Upper(REVERSE(t.TEXT)), REVERSE(w.WORD_1)) + 1, 1) - 1 > 0
    ) 

... use positions to get your substring ...
--    M a i n     S Q L :
Select      t.ID, t.TEXT,
            SubStr( t.TEXT, o.P1, o.P2 - o.P1 ) "TBL"  
From        texts t
Inner Join  last_occurrences o ON(o.ID = t.ID)

/*    R e s u l t :
        ID TEXT                                                                        TBL                                                                        
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------
         4 "select a,b ,upper(c from xyz group by c), d from t4t5t6 group by x,y;"      t4t5t6           
         3 "select a,upper(c from xyz fetch 1 or 2 from tbl), d from t333 order by a;"  t333             
         2 "select a,b,d,e from t22 fetch last one;"                                    t22              
         1 "select a,b ,upper(c from xyz), d from t1 where xyx;"                        t1             */

